# Создать переход по ссылке прямо в браузер в Spring Boot

Tags: база-данных, spring, spring-boot, ссылки

Задание, реализовать переход при нажатии на сокращенную ссылку по адресу, записанному в БД как "длинная ссылка". Нашла, что при записи в HTML  работает только оставляя начальный элемент localhost:8000/...
Как можно реализовать,чтобы эта ссылка работала полностью как автономная и открывала вкладку по адрессу длинной ссылки, записанному, как например: "https://www.google.com/" ?
Попробовала реализовать это сразу в HTML файле, так и выяснила, что a href не подходит...
Куда смотреть и что искать, подскажите, кто знает, пожалуйста :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Главная страница</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/main.css}">
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="layouts/header :: header"></div>
<div class="presentation">
    <h2>Хочешь получить короткую ссылку?</h2>
</div>
<main class="container">
    <div class="links" th:if="${!links.isEmpty()}">
        <div th:each="el : ${links}">
            <a href="/${el.long_link}"><h3 th:text="${el.short_link}"></h3></a> - вот здесь имя должно быть короткой ссылки, а переход на длинную.
            <p th:text="${el.long_link}"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${links.isEmpty()}" class="block">
        <p>Нет ссылок</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Добавить ссылку</h1>
        <form method="post" >
            <input type="text" name="long_link" placeholder="Введите длинную ссылку">
            <input type="text" name="short_link" placeholder="Введите сокращение">
            <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
<div th:replace="layouts/footer :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: уберите начальный `/`. С ним ссылка интерпретируется браузером, как относительная. нужно `<a href="${el.long_link}">`

Comment: Так тоже не работает, он вставляет в начало localhost:" http://localhost:8010/$%7Bel.long_link%7D"
Сначала так и пробовала) как сделать так, чтобы не учитывался localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось до смешного просто, добавить thymeleaf и сюда: "a th:href=..."
:)